# how to display only date from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

i m getting date from sql server database and it is displaying datetime as 1/15/2015 12:00:00 AM.

code in c# i used is:

```
dob_lbl.Text = reader[6].ToString();
```

//this is extracted using Sqlconnection so it's in array format.

i need only date to display.pls help.

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you see reader[6] in quick watch what value you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
string strDate = reader[6].ToString();
dob_lbl.Text  =  DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: i tried this bro but it didn't work. ERROR: No overload for method 'ToString takes 1 arguments'.

Comment: i guess you are getting the DateTime from sql server as string then check the edited answer...

Comment: this is not displaying date like 1986-02-02 from Sql Server. not working with all values.

Comment: if you want two digit month  then you need to add an extra `M` in ToString() function format (`"yyyy/MM/dd"`), check my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `DateTime` should help with this.

Use it like:

```
string strDate = reader[6].ToString();
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
string justDateStr = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply split the string and use the first part of the resulting array.
Something like:

```
dob_lbl.Text = reader[6].ToString().Split()[0];
```